# Add a pre-defined service name in my parameters.yml in Symfony 2.8.21

Tags: symfony, service, configuration, symfony-2.8

I am looking to configure the priority and order of services passed into another service as arguments. This is how my services are defined around the area I am working on:

services.yml:

```
appbundle.services.sms_validator:
    class:  AppBundle\Services\SMS\Validator
    arguments:
        - '@appbundle.services.acmesender'
        - '@appbundle.services.piccosender'

appbundle.services.acmesender:
    class: AppBundle\Services\SMS\AcmeSender
    arguments:
        - '@acme.client'

appbundle.services.piccosender:
    class: AppBundle\Services\SMS\PiccoSender
    arguments:
        - '@picco.client'
```

This is ideally how I would like my parameters.yml to be set out allowing me to pass `'%service_provider_primary%'` and `'%service_provider_secondary%'` into the `Validator` service.

The problem is I can't see an example like this documented anywhere. Is this how I should tackle this problem or is there another way to make this configurable without having to edit `services.yml` should I want to switch the priority of the senders?

parameters.yml:

```
parameters:
    service_provider_primary: '@appbundle.services.acmesender'
    service_provider_secondary: '@appbundle.services.piccosender'
```

Comment: You could use a compiler pass: https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/compiler_passes.html I am not aware of any way to specify a service name via a parameter.